# How to get TypeScript definitions file for a particular version of Jquery, ex 3.2.1?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, typescript, npm, typescript-typings

I'm new to TypeScript and still trying to figure it out.  I have a sample visual studio project that uses jquery version 3.2.1 and I'd like to make the TypeScript type definitions available to my project.

From the internet it appears that the authoritative source for these type definitions is https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

On that page I read

> **npm** 
> This is the preferred method. This is only available for TypeScript 2.0+ users. For example:
>   
>   npm install --save-dev @types/node

So it would seem I just need to type `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery` to get the jquery type definition file downloaded via npm.  But then I asked myself, hmm, I wonder what version of jquery those the type definition file will be for if everyone is typing the same command regardless of jquery version.  So I went over to the [npm site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery) to check and oddly it said

> This package contains type definitions for jQuery 1.10.x / (http://jquery.com/).

yet, the last update was "Last updated: Sat, 11 Mar 2017 00:13:28 GMT".

So that just seems odd, why would there be a recent update to an npm module that is for jquery 1.10.x?  And why would the latest version of the jquery type def on npm be for such an old version of jquery?  2.0 maybe but 1.10.x?  So I'm guessing that perhaps these type defs are the latest and greatest and whoever is maintaining the npm package just isn't updating the summary?  But how can I confirm that?  I downloaded the module and tried to discern from that what version of jquery the type defs were for but was unable to tell for sure.

So here's my question.  How does a person get TypeScript definitions file for a particular version of Jquery, ex 3.2.1?

Comment: If you open [the index.d.ts file on GitHub (the latest version)](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts), the first line says *Type definitions for jQuery 1.10.x / 2.0.x*. There are no types created for later versions. See [this issue on the DefinitelyTyped GitHub](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15733) for a discussion about types for jQuery 3.

Comment: Saw that but it didn't make sense to me that the type defs could be for 1.10.x and 2.x at the same time.  :-)  Your link to the github issue was informative.   If you post your comment as an answer and point out that there are no typedefs for jquery 3.x I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types you're getting now are the most recent version of the types for jQuery.

There weren't many changes between 1.10.x and 2.0.x, so the type definitions work for both.

There's [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15733) in which someone asks for new definitions for jQuery 3.x. Unfortunately, no one's volunteered to add type definitions for later versions of jQuery, so they'll remain at those older versions until someone does.

Answer (score 12):

Hi a little late to this but this is what I found after I looked in the index.d.ts file, a comment in the first line states the version of compatible JQuery.

`npm install @types/jquery@1.x` will get you JQuery 1.x definitions

`npm install @types/jquery@2.x` will get you JQuery 2.x definitions

`npm install @types/jquery@3.x` will get you JQuery 3.x definitions

Answer (score 3):

You can print all version of specific npm package using one of these two commands:

`npm view package-name versions`

OR

`npm i package-name@whatever` (You'll get an error, but it prints all available versions)

Then just install specific version by running:

`npm i package-name@version`

---

So for jquery types you would run:

`npm view @types/jquery versions`

You see all the versions (currently latest 2.0.41). You install specific version:

`npm install --save-dev @types/jquery@2.0.41`

Comment: That's kind cool but there isn't really any way to know which version of jquery the npm package @types/jquery@2.0.41 is for.  (sigh)